# NTP server setup using internet in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ntp

NTP server configuration using internet/server pools

```
server 3.in.pool.ntp.org
server 3.asia.pool.ntp.org
server 2.asia.pool.ntp.org
```

and i started ntp service

```
[root@hpfsdev ~]# service ntp start
* Starting NTP server ntpd                                            [ OK ]
```

When i check whether ntp server is working or not using ntpq -p it shows output

I checked the ntp process

```
ps -ef|grep ntp
ntp      11258     1  0 15:29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 117:126
root     12773 10748  0 17:53 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ntp
```

I tried to ping this ip's it is working fine and i checked udp port 123 it is also working fine.

Everything is working fine where is the problem plzz let me know...

Comment: when i check the status of ntp server
ntpq -p
 #                                                                                                            remote      refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 ns02.hns.net.in .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 time.iqnet.com  .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 chobi.paina.jp  .INIT.          16 u    - 1024    0    0.000    0.000   0.000

Comment: You have to add update in your post and not in the comments (that should be deleted). Then give a better explanation and formatting to the text of the question (if you want that someone try to answer).

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: If the current system time is very wrong, adjustment can take some time. You could try to add the `-g` flag to the options. (or even -x)

Comment: I am using linux machine not windows.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is keep your system clock accurate, then you really don't need to install the ntp server.  Just add `ntpdate ntpservername` to your crontab, so that it runs every hour or so, and that should do the trick.

Comment: which ntpserver name i should give from pool of indian ntp servers?

Comment: You can use any ntp server.  For example, you can use `ntp.ubuntu.com`.  It doesn't matter which timezone you are in, your system will adjust the time to your local time (if you've set the timezone on your system).

Comment: What happens if you run the command from the command line?  FYI, you need to run the command as root.

Comment: ya i run it as root user.     
the output is as follows
root@ctel-desktop:~# ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com
24 Feb 18:09:17 ntpdate[4467]: the NTP socket is in use, exiting

Comment: it sounds like the ntp service that you started (above) may still be running.  Check if that's the case, using `ps -ef|grep ntp` like you did previously,  If the service is still running, stop it, then see if the command-line command works.

Comment: after stoping ntp service when i issue command it shows 
25 Feb 09:52:46 ntpdate[6273]: no server suitable for synchronization found
can u please update the solution as soon as possible

Comment: Your hosting provider may be blocking NTP packets.  See http://askubuntu.com/questions/429306/ntpdate-no-server-suitable-for-synchronization-found

Comment: Where can I download `ntpdate `?

Comment: On Debian / Ubuntu:  sudo apt install ntpdate